# How To call JIRA server API from outside (Microsoft flow)

Tags: api, rest, https, jira, power-automate

I have a requirement to call the JIRA rest API hosted on premise from Microsoft Flow (HTTP call)
I know that using basic authentication with username and password is not recommended,
And in JIRA on premise as I found , we cannot use API keys (not like JIRA cloud),

So what is the best method to call the JIRA API ?
in Microsoft Flow their is an option OAuth Active Directory , I suppose it's for Azure hosted applications ? (I'm not sure)

Thank you

Comment: If you're unable to use basic authentication and API tokens, I'm unaware of any other way, sorry.

Comment: They  recommend  using  the  OAuth, but to be honnest I dont know  how  to  use  it  with  Flow (basic Oauth will be my last  choice  )

Comment: I haven't worked with Jira API, but I have to use OAuth tokens in Flow to access the Microsoft Graph APIs. I send a request to an authorization endpoint with a secret key that I configured in Microsoft Azure and it sends me back an OAuth token that I can then use in future calls as authorization. Do you know if the Jira API has an endpoint like that?